# CSS selector for nth in a series of immediately adjacent tags

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to implement a sort of zebra striping, but I want to constrain the eligible tags to those that are immediately adjacent to each other.

For example

```
<span class="match">a</span>
<span class="match">b</span>
<span class="match">c</span>
<span class="nomatch">d</span>
<span class="match">e</span>
```

Kinda sorta CSS that doesn't really work

```
.match + .match:nth-child(2n){ ... }
```

The spans a, b and c should be zebra striped because the are immediately adjacent to each other, but e should not. Can nth-child be used in this way?

Comment: Do you mean after every last `.nomatch`, the next immediate `.match` should start at 0? Something like `[white, black, white, red, red, white, black]` where `.nomatch` is red?

Comment: Can you expand the testcase? I *think* I have an idea, but I'm slightly confused on exactly what should be happening.

Comment: @BoltClock: "after every last .nomatch" not quite - it's to be read after any non .match + .match sequence.

Comment: An illustration would be helpful.

Comment: For what it's worth, this is the pure CSS idea I had, still not sure it's what you want. I changed it to look like your jsFiddle on the accepted answer: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/2YGvE/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xt8FA/1/)**

```
$(".match + .match").each(function() {
    $(this).addClass("stripe").prev().addClass("stripe");
});
```

Comment: That may be on the right track, but it only highlights all of matches in the set, but does not stripe them.

Comment: with a little extra styling, your method works. Updated the fiddle to match. http://jsfiddle.net/appsinyourpants/xt8FA/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
:nth-child(even)
:nth-child(odd)
```

Or are you looking to do something more complex?

Comment: even or odd will stripe the matching elements with class .match. Not sure what else he could be trying to do.